# Opencart: Add extra features under the same product

Tags: selection, mouseover, categories

I am new to programing and to Opencart. I am populating a site for a beauty shop http://sunrisebeautysupplies.com/Go_oshopping . I need when my customers go to a particular product, (lets say wigs), somewhere on the same page to display images of colors available at the store - these images are representaed with number variables  since some products have #s as their ids in the market.  Example - wigs # 121 refers to dark or wigs # 131 refering to dark brown. The customer  uses mouse over for quicker perusal and color selection without page reloading and open on a space within the page. in admin section, I need to be able to add these extra features under the same product. After the customer selection, their choice of coler is included in the order or checkout proceess.

I have added a table with images as test as seen here: http://sunrisebeautysupplies.com/Go_oshopping but I need each product page to feature its own category.

Any help is much appreciated.

Mkarimu

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try with the Catalog->Options->Insert and select Image type, or actually The select type (with image you will be able to do what you requiered).

If you have problems tell me and I can indicate you a little bit more :)